# Como obtener el nombre de usuario actual para enviarlo a un PermisoAttribute como Parametro

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo una clase PermisoAttribute que es heredada de un ActionFilterAttribute, la que muestro a continuacion.

```
public class PermisoAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public string username { get; set; }
            public int ProgramId { get; set; }
            public int ModuleId { get; set; }

            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

                if (!permisos(this.username,this.ProgramId,this.ModuleId))
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                    {
                        controller = "Home",
                        action = "Denegado"
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
```

Como pueden observar esta toma como parametro si el usuario tiene o no permisos para saber si el usuario puede ejecutar la accion, invocando una clase permisos que recibe un username, programaid, ModuleId como parametros y retorna true o false segun el usuario tiene o no permisos.

Aqui como pretendo usar mi clase PermisoAttribute

```
[HttpGet]
[Permiso(username = User.Identity.Name, ModuleId = 3, ProgramId = 2)]
public ActionResult Transactions()
{
   // codigo de la accion. 
}
```

pero recibo este error a usar el codigo `User.Identity.Name`

> Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'Controller.User'

Lo que quiero es obtener el nombre del usuario actual para enviarlo y ver si dicho usuario tiene permisos o no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar el error que te está marcando se debe a que no puedes utilizar variables en los atributos, es decir, solo debes manejar valores estáticos "duros", por ejemplo:

```
[Permiso(username = "Admin", ModuleId = 3, ProgramId = 2)]
```

En segundo lugar, no es necesario que establezcas el nombre de usuario en un atributo de autorización, ya que esa información está almacenada ya en los datos de la sesión, lo único que debes hacer es llamarlo desde dentro del atributo con `filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`:

```
public class PermisoAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        if (!permisos(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, this.ProgramId, this.ModuleId))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Denegado"
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Como comentario final, no es *necesario* que coloques los atributos así:

```
[HttpGet]
[Permiso(ModuleId = 3, ProgramId = 2)]
```

sino que puedes agregar los que necesites con comas, por ejemplo:

```
[HttpGet, Permiso(ModuleId = 3, ProgramId = 2)]
```